# How to make Bootstrap popover appear next to different div?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use Bootstrap to create a popover next to a div I specifiy.

The Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) suggests that I use data-container html attribute for this purpose. Something like: data-container="my-div".

So I first define the div, I want the popover to appear next to:

```
<div id="hello">
   I'd like for the popover to show next to this.
</div>
```

And then the popover trigger button, with data-container pointing to the div's `hello` id:

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
   data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-original-title="Creativity Tuts" data-container="#hello">pop
</a>
```

However, I can't get it to work. The popover keeps showing next to the button.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VUZhL/2564/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be an option for you to trigger the `popover` from that button, but have the `popover` contents inside the `#hello` element?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/qg7j6r6t/)

HTML:

```
<p>Click on button to see Popover</p>
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary">pop
</a>
<br/><br/>
<br/><br/>
<div id="hello" data-content="This is the body of Popover"
   data-original-title="Creativity Tuts" rel="popover">
   I'd like for the popover to show next to this.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').click(function() {
        $('#hello').popover('show');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#hello {
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, the popover appears on the right side of the element. You're probably going to want to put `data-placement="place"` within your `<a>`, replacing "place" with something like "top", "left" etc.